# Postgresql query error with variable assigning

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hopefully this question will be simple enough. I need some help with my postgresql query. I want to create a function that does a *quite* complex thing so i will not go into specifics. I will post the whole code for reference and the part that errors (middle bit of the posted code):

EDIT:

ALL problems have been fixed(unfo none of the answers given were any help). Now however i have a new problem!

Here is the updated code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetDevicesForPush(alertId INTEGER,appId INTEGER,isTest BOOLEAN,notificationId INTEGER,stateCode VARCHAR) 
    RETURNS "PushDevice" AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF($5 IS NOT NULL) THEN
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO PushDevice(DeviceId,PushNotificationId, pushId,deviceType,sound)
            SELECT DISTINCT  d.id, $4,d.pushId,d.type,d.sound FROM Device d  inner join DeviceLocation dl ON  d.id = dl.DeviceId 
            WHERE dl.FIPScode in (select FIPScode from CountyFIPS  where stateCode=$5) AND dl.AppId=$2 AND d.pushId is not null and d.pushId <>'' and d.pushId<>'1234-5678-9101-2345-3456' and d.isTest =$3 and d.enableNotification=1 and dl.isDeleted=0
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PushDevice t where t.DeviceId=d.id AND t.PushNotificationId=$4);
        END;
    ELSE 

        DECLARE epiCentre VARCHAR;
                        magnitude FLOAT;

    BEGIN
        SELECT polygon INTO epiCentre from alert  where id=$1 and disablePush=FALSE;
    END;

        IF(epiCentre IS NOT NULL) THEN
        BEGIN
                INSERT INTO PushDevice(DeviceId,PushNotificationId, pushId,deviceType,sound)
                SELECT DISTINCT  d.id, $4,d.pushId,d.type,d.sound FROM Device d  inner join DeviceLocation dl   ON  d.id = dl.DeviceId 
                WHERE  dl.AppId=$2 AND d.pushId is not null and d.pushId <>'' and d.pushId<>'1234-5678-9101-2345-3456' and d.isTest =$3  and ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_GeometryFromText(epiCentre), ST_GeometryFromText(geoPoint))<=d.radius * 1609.344 and magnitude>= d.magnitude and d.enableNotification=1 and dl.isDeleted=0
                AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PushDevice t where t.DeviceId=d.id AND t.PushNotificationId=$4);
        END;

        SELECT pd.* FROM  PushDevice pd
        WHERE pd.PushNotificationId =$4 and pd.sentAt is null;

END

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And i get the followig error:

[Err] ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 35: $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

I tried putting a semicolon after END , removing END completly etc. Can someone proficient tell me his opinion on this?

EDIT2: Come on guys!!! i forgot the END IF; statement!! that was the error!

Comment: It is completely unclear what you want or where your error comes from. The errors you quote do not appear in the code you provide, for instance. But you could start by getting your `SELECT ... INTO` right: `SELECT polygon, CAST(severity as decimal(3,1)) INTO epiCentre, magnitude FROM alert WHERE id=$1 AND disablePush=FALSE;`

Comment: "unfo none of the answers given were any help". Geez! Perhaps you were not supplied with an answer that solved your issue, but you may want to review your original post and try to distill your own question. And trust me, going "into specifics" of your "_quite_ complex thing" will help the community come up with an answer, should you care to actually receive some help. I have found at least a handful of issues with your code, but until you give me some reason to believe that you actually appreciate help I'll just hang on to it.

Comment: You might want to start by specifying what you want the function to return because the name of a table it isn't (the list of newly inserted records?). You also declare `magnitude` but you don't initialize it and `geoPoint` is neither declared nor initialized. Elaborate these _quite_ complex things and an answer may be forthcoming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a semi colon after the last `END`

```
END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: if i do that then this is how it looks:

  SELECT pd.* FROM  PushDevice pd
  WHERE pd.PushNotificationId =$4 and pd.sentAt is null;

END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


[Err] ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 33: END;
            ^

Comment: @Martino My answer fixes the error reported in your question. There are more than one error in your query.

Comment: cool, your answer is the closest thing to an answer so its cool. Just a bit disappointed i didnt get a good answer as someone proficcient would spot the error off the bat :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in how postgresql is handling the conversion between the decimal and the varchar. I would futz around with the size of the varchar in your column or explicitly cast the decimal into a varchar.

ex:

```
CAST(severity as decimal(3,1)) INTO magnitude
```

Try using the to_char function...
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-formatting.html

Comment: That is not it unfortunately. If i completely omit the magnitude part i still get the same error with this:

 SELECT polygon INTO epiCentre from alert where id=$1 and disablePush=FALSE;

Comment: What about the polygon into epiCentre portion? Is the problem with the conversion possibly there? What size varchar is polygon? epiCentre?

Comment: it has length 100. But does it matter? how would i cast the length exactly? would i declare variable varchar(100)?

Comment: Yes. Declare your varchar variable the same size as the varchar in your column.